# Maven installing hue Could not find artifact tools.jar

Tags: java, maven, hue

I'm trying to install hue through git centos 6.5 64
error

```
Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
```

I have
    dime910 ~/hue# ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/lib/tools.jar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18M Sep  5 08:39 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/lib/tools.jar

I ran

```
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/lib/tools.jar
```

Searched my system have only 2 pom.files
    /root/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/pom.xml
    /root/hue/maven/pom.xml

`/root/hue` is the directory created by git

to each of the pom files - still get the error
seems the .. in the error message is messing up -

I can't find why...

more details...

```
dime910 ~/hue # mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.20.5.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

dime910 ~/hue/maven :( # echo $JAVA_HOME
    /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64


    alternatives --display java
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java.
```

I think I've done my homework and I'm reaching out for help - hopefully someone sees this.

Comment: to the pom files <dependency>  
    <systemPath>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency> 
 <profiles>
          <systemPath>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  </profiles>

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle JDK](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_oracle_jdk_installation.html?scroll=topic_29_1) is recommend for installing Hue.